# Changed const variable to static variables

Tags: c#

I adh some constants in my project.

```
private const int refercePosition = 0.3;
```

I shifted the constants to the Settings file of my project (i.e into App.config) and using now in my project as.

```
private static int refPos = Properties.Settings.Default.referencePosition;
```

Is this a good practice to decalre the variable as static instead of constant?
There are approximately 10 other constants in my project which which I did the same.

BTW, since App.config variables are runtime configurable but does declaring a variable as static defeat that purpose?

Comment: You could also make a static property with only a `get` accessor.

Comment: You should probably add the `readonly` modifier to the declaration if had originally been declared as `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a drop in replacement since now `refPos` can be modified during runtime. If that is your purpose that is fine, otherwise

```
private static readonly int refPos = Properties.Settings.Default.referencePosition;
```

makes `refPos` readonly during runtime. More close to the nature of a `const`.

You may also want to look at the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that a const cannot be changed at runtime, but a static property can be changed by your application at runtime.
So if the value never changes it can be a const...

Answer (score 1):

Constants are inherently static so converting from `const` to `static readonly` is not uncommon, in cases where you cannot declare a value as a run time constant anymore. Also note that only `User` scoped settings can be changed during run time. If those settings are `Application` scoped, there won't be a difference. If you're going to use `User` scoped settings, I advice you to use them directly in your code, since as you said, then can change at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

**when static instead of constant?**
constants should be used when it is very unlikely that the value will ever change, or if no external apps/libs will be using the constant. Static readonly fields should be used when run-time calculation is required, or if external consumers are a factor.